# Javascript regex: match any character that is not in the set of symbols (but only if this symbol doesn't follow a backslash)

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex which matches any character that is not in the set of symbols (but only if this symbol doesn't follow a backslash)

Is there any one line solution?

sample input: `"Test1\,test2,test3\<\>test4<>test5"`
reqex to improve: `/[^,<>]+/`

expected output: [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `\` is not at the first position of a match you may use this regex:

```sh
[^,<>\\]+(?:\\.[^,<>\\]*)*
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `[^,<>\\]+`: Match 1 or more of any character that are not inside the the `[...]`
- `\\.` match any escaped character

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NZiG4W/1)

If `\` can be at first position then you may use:

```sh
(?:\\.|[^,<>\\]+)+
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/Ole5nN/1)